# MockMVC how to test exception and response code in the same test case

Tags: java, spring, testing, spring-mvc, junit

I want to assert that an exception is raised and that the server returns an 500 internal server error.

To highlight the intent a code snippet is provided:

```
thrown.expect(NestedServletException.class);
this.mockMvc.perform(post("/account")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .content(requestString))
            .andExpect(status().isInternalServerError());
```

Of course it dosen't matter if I write `isInternalServerError` or `isOk`.
The test will pass regardless if an exception is thrown below the `throw.except` statement.

How would you go about to solve this?

Answer (score 26):

If you have an **exception handler** and you want to test for a specific exception, you could also assert that the instance is valid in the resolved exception.

```
.andExpect(result -> assertTrue(result.getResolvedException() instanceof WhateverException))
```

**UPDATE** (gavenkoa) Don't forget to inject `@ExceptionHandler` annotated methods to the test context or exception will occur at `.perform()` instead of capturing it with `.andExpect()`, basically register:

```java
@ControllerAdvice
public class MyExceptionHandlers {
    @ExceptionHandler(BindException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<?> handle(BindException ex) { ... }
}
```

with `@Import(value=...)` or `@ContextConfiguration(classes=...)` or by other means.

Comment: Really nice one!! Really clean and neat! Saved me a lifetime of trouble :)

Comment: To be more specific in order to use `MvcResult.perform(...).andExpect()` where there is an exception in `@Controller` you need to inject `@ExceptionHandler` into your Spring Test Context or it throws exception right in `.perform()` just before `.andExpect()` )) Thx mate!

Comment: @gavenkoa can you explain what you mean by _or it throws exception right in .perform() just before .andExpect() )_ ?
I have a void method stubbed and  wherein the service is annotated with @ MockBean and it is meant to throw and error but everycall to the api endpoint results in 200 instead of the exception return.

Answer (score 14):

You can get a reference to the [MvcResult](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/MvcResult.html) and the possibly resolved exception and check with general JUnit assertions...

```
MvcResult result = this.mvc.perform(
        post("/api/some/endpoint")
                .contentType(TestUtil.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
                .content(TestUtil.convertObjectToJsonBytes(someObject)))
        .andDo(print())
        .andExpect(status().is4xxClientError())
        .andReturn();

Optional<SomeException> someException = Optional.ofNullable((SomeException) result.getResolvedException());

someException.ifPresent( (se) -> assertThat(se, is(notNullValue())));
someException.ifPresent( (se) -> assertThat(se, is(instanceOf(SomeException.class))));
```

Comment: If you expect the exception in the test, you can just use `assertTrue(result.getResolvedException() instanceof SomeException)`

Comment: This seems very confusing. You expect an exception, but use `Optional.ifPresent()`. This would at first glance suggest that `someException` could be missing, and the assertions would just be ignored.

Comment: Both valid points.... I was working with Optional<?> a lot back then so it may have swayed my design style a bit

Answer (score 8):

You can try something as below -

1. Create a custom matcher

   ```
   public class CustomExceptionMatcher extends
   TypeSafeMatcher<CustomException> {

   private String actual;
   private String expected;

   private CustomExceptionMatcher (String expected) {
       this.expected = expected;
   }

   public static CustomExceptionMatcher assertSomeThing(String expected) {
       return new CustomExceptionMatcher (expected);
   }

   @Override
   protected boolean matchesSafely(CustomException exception) {
       actual = exception.getSomeInformation();
       return actual.equals(expected);
   }

   @Override
   public void describeTo(Description desc) {
       desc.appendText("Actual =").appendValue(actual)
           .appendText(" Expected =").appendValue(
                   expected);

   }
   }
   ```
2. Declare a `@Rule` in JUnit class as below -

   ```
   @Rule
   public ExpectedException exception = ExpectedException.none();
   ```
3. Use the Custom matcher in test case as -

   ```
   exception.expect(CustomException.class);
   exception.expect(CustomException
           .assertSomeThing("Some assertion text"));
   this.mockMvc.perform(post("/account")
       .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
       .content(requestString))
       .andExpect(status().isInternalServerError());
   ```

**P.S.:** I have provided a generic pseudo code which you can customize as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I recently encountered the same error, and instead of using MockMVC I created an integration test as follows:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { MyTestConfiguration.class })
public class MyTest {
    
    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate testRestTemplate;
    
    @Test
    public void myTest() throws Exception {
        
        ResponseEntity<String> response = testRestTemplate.getForEntity("/test", String.class);
        
        assertEquals(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, response.getStatusCode(), "unexpected status code");
        
    }   
}
```

and

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = NotDesiredConfiguration.class)
public class MyTestConfiguration {
    
    @RestController
    public class TestController {
        
        @GetMapping("/test")
        public ResponseEntity<String> get() throws Exception{
            throw new Exception("not nice");
        }           
    }   
}
```

this post was very helpful: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/7321

Answer (score -7):

In your controller:

```
throw new Exception("Athlete with same username already exists...");
```

In your test:

```
    try {
        mockMvc.perform(post("/api/athlete").contentType(contentType).
                content(TestUtil.convertObjectToJsonBytes(wAthleteFTP)))
                .andExpect(status().isInternalServerError())
                .andExpect(content().string("Athlete with same username already exists..."))
                .andDo(print());
    } catch (Exception e){
        //sink it
    }
```

Comment: This way the test will always pass regardless the status code or response

Comment: One of the best practise in Java is to never throw an Exception. You should create a specific one.