# Testing thrown exception in controller

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-mvc

I want to perform a test on a controller method which throws an exception. The method is something like this:

```
@RequestMapping("/do")
public ResponseEntity doIt(@RequestBody Request request) throws Exception {
    throw new NullPointerException();
}
```

When I try to test this method with following code part,

```
 mockMvc.perform(post("/do")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(JSON.toJson(request)))
```

`NestedServletException` is thrown from Spring libraries. How can I test that `NullPointerException` is thrown instead of `NestedServletException`?

Comment: You are doing POST and controller method matches GET. When you change it to GET you will get NPE.

Comment: @NikolaB empty method indicates that all HTTP methods are mapped to `doIt`. http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-requestmapping

Comment: My bad try catching the NestedServletException and invoke getRootCause() method and see what is returned.

Comment: The original exception is returned by getRootCause(). But I wonder if there is some configuration that Spring throws the original exception.

Comment: Not really sure what you mean but try adding void method to controller with @ExceptionHandler(NullPointerException.class) annotation and parameter NullPointerException npe and in body of method throw npe.

Comment: I got it you have to invoke doIt method on created(or injected) controller and surround it with a try catch block in test method because this way you are testing whole framework instead of specified method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Our solution is rather a workaround: The exception is caught in advice and error body is returned as HTTP response. Here is how the mock works:

```
MockMvc mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(controller)
                        .setHandlerExceptionResolvers(withExceptionControllerAdvice())
                        .build();

private ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver withExceptionControllerAdvice() {
    final ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver exceptionResolver = new ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver() {
        @Override
        protected ServletInvocableHandlerMethod getExceptionHandlerMethod(final HandlerMethod handlerMethod, final Exception exception) {
            Method method = new ExceptionHandlerMethodResolver(TestAdvice.class).resolveMethod(exception);
            if (method != null) {
                return new ServletInvocableHandlerMethod(new TestAdvice(), method);
            }
            return super.getExceptionHandlerMethod(handlerMethod, exception);
        }
    };
    exceptionResolver.afterPropertiesSet();
    return exceptionResolver;
}
```

Advice class:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class TestAdvice {
    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    public Object exceptionHandler(Exception e) {
        return new HttpEntity<>(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

After than, following test method passes successfully:

```
@Test
public void testException
    mockMvc.perform(post("/exception/path"))
        .andExpect(status().is5xxServerError())
        .andExpect(content().string("Exception body"));
}
```

Comment: What is controller in MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(controller) line?

Comment: The controller bean that is being tested, it is injected to the test class.

Answer (score 2):

Easier way is to inject `@ExceptionHandler` into your Spring Test Context or it throws exception right in `MockMvc.perform()` just before `.andExpect()`.

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { My_ExceptionHandler_AreHere.class })
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class Test {
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        RequestBuilder requestBuilder = MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/update")
                .param("branchId", "13000")
                .param("triggerId", "1");
        MvcResult mvcResult = mvc.perform(requestBuilder)
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().is4xxClientError())
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8))
                .andExpect(__ -> Assert.assertThat(
                        __.getResolvedException(),
                        CoreMatchers.instanceOf(SecurityException.class)))
                .andReturn();
}
```

That way `MvcResult.getResolvedException()` holds `@Controller`'s exception!

https://stackoverflow.com/a/61016827/173149